# How to let option expressions simplfy in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to understand options in Isabelle (2020), and couldn't understand why some simple expressions of option do not compute or simplify as expected.

For example, I'd expect that

```
value "some (1::nat)"
```

should return an `"nat option"` type, yet, it returns an unspecified type:

```
"some 1"
  :: "'a
```

More over, from the type signature, I'd expect the `the` function the return the value "inside" the option, so that "the (some (1::nat))" is just `(1::nat)`.

However,

```
value "the (some (1::nat))"
```

returns a seemingly not very useful type:

```
"the (some 1)"
  :: "'a"
```

, which isn't `nat`. Then the result isn't very useful, e.g.

```
 value "the (some (1::nat)) + 2"
```

returns

```
"the (some 1) + (1 + 1)"
  :: "'a"
```

(I expected the result to be `"3::nat"`)

*Is this by design or am I missing something about `the`, or how options simplify/compute in Isabelle?*

( I have no prior knowledge about Isabelle options, and I am just assuming it's similar to Haskell's Maybe. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C-click on the shows that the definition is:

```
datatype 'a option =
    None
  | Some (the: 'a)
```

> It is Some, not some.

There is a hint to see that `some` is not defined: the color is not the same as the color from `the`.